# chaplin.js SyncMachine calls

Tags: web-applications, coffeescript, chaplinjs

I am currently creating a CollectionView with a loadingIndicator in [chaplin.js](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin).
In the initialize function of my corresponding collection I have to call `initSyncMachine()` like this

```
initialize: ->
    super
    @initSyncMachine()
```

I realize that this is necessary in order for the collection to trigger the sync events my CollectionView listens to. But do I really have to call `beginSync()` and all the other functions as well? Isn't that done by the [sync method in backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync)?

My initialize function currently looks like this:

```
initialize: ->
  super
  @initSyncMachine()
    @fetch
      success: =>
        @finishSync()
      error: =>
        @abortSync()
```

The [chaplin.js facebook example](https://github.com/chaplinjs/facebook-example/blob/master/coffee/models/likes.coffee) does this, but has legitimate reason to do so.
It overrides the `fetch()` method and calls `beginSync()` while calling `finishSync()` in another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is something that has not yet been implemented. So yes: I will have to call the functions manually.
It seems like this is something that is going to be implemented though: https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin/issues/91